# Is it possible to see sbt's execution plan?

Tags: sbt

An sbt build configuration can get quite complex. When it does, it's hard to tell exactly what sbt will do because you're not sure you did the right thing in the build definition. And if you have a large project, running full build and test cycles to test changes is really painful and slow.

For example, I'm configuring sbt to build and test my project in parallel. It would be great if I could ask sbt to report:

- exactly how many JVMs will be forked and when
- exactly what options each JVM will be assigned
- exactly what tasks will be assigned to each JVM
- exactly how tests will be grouped in the JVMs

Perhaps some of this information can only be determined by doing some work, perhaps even by performing the full build and test. But it would nonetheless be great to have some kind of neat report that clearly lays out what's going on.

Does sbt offer such a facility?

Comment: @Jacek - The configuration of JVMs and distribution of tests/tasks is an example of something someone might want to see a plan for, but there are probably other use cases for an execution plan. (Also, the example mentioned number of tasks per JVM and not the other way around.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it could easily be achieved in sbt.

There's `inspect` command that could tell you quite a bit what you need, but it's just a small piece comparing to what you're after and lots is missing to have a complete plan.

```
> help inspect
inspect <key>

    For a plain setting, the value bound to the key argument is displayed using its toString method.
    Otherwise, the type of task ("Task" or "Input task") is displayed.

    "Dependencies" shows the settings that this setting depends on.

    "Reverse dependencies" shows the settings that depend on this setting.

    When a key is resolved to a value, it may not actually be defined in the requested scope.
    In this case, there is a defined search sequence.
    "Delegates" shows the scopes that are searched for the key.
    "Provided by" shows the scope that contained the value returned for the key.

    "Related" shows all of the scopes in which the key is defined.

inspect tree <key>

    Displays `key` and its dependencies in a tree structure.
    For settings, the value bound to the setting is displayed and for tasks, the type of the task is shown.

inspect uses <key>

    Displays the settings and tasks that directly depend on `key`.

inspect definitions <key>

    Displays the scopes in which `key` is defined.
```

Read [Inspect the build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Inspect-the-Build.html) to learn about the command.

You may also want to use `show` with some settings like `fork` or `javaOptions`:

```
> help fork
If true, forks a new JVM when running.  If false, runs in the same JVM as the build.

> help javaOptions
Options passed to a new JVM when forking.
```

See [Forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html) in the official documentation.

I would like to have such a tool, too.

Comment: [`inspect`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Inspecting-Settings.html) looks like a useful tool. Is there an example usage of `inspect` you can provide that can shows some of the information mentioned in the example?